# Obtaining handle to Collection/Array object in @PreFilter and @PostFilter in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring Security, @PreFilter and @PostFilter can be used to trim/prune the argument/return object and filterObject references each element in the object and is used to loop through the argument/return Collection/Array.

However, I need to get a handle to the actual Collection/Array as a whole and not specific elements in the context. Is there any way to do this?

The reason is that I am creating an externalized authorization service that is used by Spring Security to query and prune the collection/array and this service supports querying for multiple answers in a single question. Once I get a reference to the object as a whole, I can iterate though the elements myself to create this request to the externalized service.

Can this be done in Spring Security? I am implementing this as an custom express handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the return value is modifiable, you can use @PostAuthorize. For example:

```
@PostAuthorize("@mySecurityFilter.filter(authentication, returnObject)")
List<String> findAllMessages();
```

This assumes you created a Bean by the name of "mySecurityFilter" that looks something like this:

```
@Component
public class MySecurityFilter {

    public boolean filter(Authentication authentication, List<String> domain) {
        // submit to service and get back all allowed values
        List<String> allowed = Arrays.asList("Hello");

        Iterator<String> iValues = domain.iterator();
        while(iValues.hasNext()) {
            String value = iValues.next();
            if(!allowed.contains(value)) {
                iValues.remove();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you are re-implementing PostFilter using PostAuthorize? :) That would work for my case I guess. Is there a similar approach for PreXXXX as well?

Comment: You cannot access the return value using PreAuthorize because the value has not been returned yet. However, you could manipulate the arguments.